# Should I edit the answer to my own question

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, accepted-answer

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow to which I have gotten multiple answers.

One of them I find has a bit more detailed information really helping me understand what is happening.

Here is the question : [How is a string value used as a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849404/how-is-a-string-value-used-as-a-boolean)

Sriram Sakthivel's explanation answers really well what I am asking but leaves out the importance of Option Strict mentionned by other answers.

Should I edit the answer to add mention of `Option Strict` and then accept it or should I simply accept Sriram Sakthivel's answer and leave the references to `option strict` in other answers?

Maybe I should simply accept it and add a comment to mention the extra information ?

Comment: Leaving a comment suggesting that the poster of the answer adds the additional information would be the best first step. Often times, the poster will be interested in improving their answer. Making substantial edits to answers, which includes adding content, is somewhat iffy. You should be able to find other discussions of the general topic.